# How to order the matrixes?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I would I go about ordering the matrixes with parenthesizes such as (A1)(A2(A3A4)) based on the two matrixes calculated

```
import sys
s=[[]]
from pprint import pprint
def order(i,j):
    if(i==j):
        print("A" + str(i))
    else:
        k = s[i][j]
        print("(")
        order(i,k)
        order(k+1,j)
        print(")")


def minmult(p, n,par):
    m = [[0 for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)]
    s = [[0 for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)]

for i in range(1, n):
    m[i][i] = 0
    s[i][i] = 0


for L in range(2, n):
    for i in range(1, n-L+1):
        j = i+L-1
        m[i][j] = sys.maxsize
        for k in range(i, j):
            q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j]
            if q < m[i][j]:
                m[i][j] = q
                s[i][j]=k
            print(str(order(i,j)))
pprint(m)
pprint(s)
return m[1][n-1]


array=[10,4,5,20,2,50]
size = len(array)
print(str(minmult(array,size,0)))
```

No idea how to make the method order work any help would great.

Comment: can you add example of input and desired output?

Comment: Your code fails with a "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function". Since your question appears to be about an algorithm, not about your code throwing an exception (there are several lines in your code elsewhere that will cause the code to crash), could you please clarify your question? Is it the algorithm you have a problem with, or running the code?